# Rails generate migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got below command run on console

```
rails g migration payslips first_name:string last_name:string
```

But this just generates empty file like below

```
class Payslips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

I cannot find the reason why. Is there something wrong with the console generate command?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with the generator not the input you give to the generator? Are you trying to add columns to a table or create a new table? Either way, you have to specify what you trying to do. Have a look at rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration

Comment: `migration generator` does not create migration file with column adds but just an empty file I already have model for Payslip so I need to create a new migration file only

Comment: Try `rails g migration AddFirstNameAndLastNameToPayslips first_name:string last_name:string`. Rails isn't as intelligent to guess what you are trying to do just by telling it the table name you know. Please [read the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration)

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct functionality, if you want to create a model then you need to run:

```bash
rails g model payslips first_name:string last_name:string
```

Then you get:

```rb
class CreatePayslips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :payslips do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the word: **Create** before your table name.

$ rails generate migration CreateProducts name:string part_number:string

generates:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :part_number
    end
  end
end
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: This generates an empty migration for me. Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 2.1.5p273

Comment: for mee too: ```class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming that your model has been created**, you must be more explicit when explaining what you really want to do :

```
rails g migration add_first_name_and_last_name_to_payslips first_name:string last_name:string
```

The above tells the migrator to add first_name and last_name to the payslips table, so you end up with this migration :

```
class AddFirstNameAndLastNameToPayslips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :payslips, :first_name, :string
    add_column :payslips, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate migration alone to modify the tables. But to create new table you have to generate model so that it will generate create table migration for the corresponding model(like @efrenfuentes said)

Or you can try what you want to do with a plugin called `migration_for`

`rails plugin install git://github.com/capotej/migration_for.git`

`rails g migration_for create_table:payslips add_column:payslips:first_name:string add_column:payslips:last_name:string`